# .bat file to check servers are up

Tags: networking, batch-file, ping, automation

We are running ERP software which is deployed to number of servers. 
If we get a problem, we usually restart the servers and cross check that all the servers are running (just check if we get login page or not). 
Alternatively, we ping to IP address `192.XXX.X.XX` to check the 'reply'.

This checking process is time consuming. 
How can I create a `.bat` file to check and give me results like

```
192.XXX.X.XX:80 OK
192.XXX.X.XX:81 OK
192.XXX.X.YY:80 No Reply
```

Comment: look online for `wget` for windows, wrap it in a loop and check errorlevel, if login page available or not it will return different result

Comment: curl should be an good alternative to wget

Comment: I guess there are two things here, testing the server is up and testing the services it provide are up.  You mention a login page so I assume it would be better to check the web service it provides is up?  Ping will tell you if the computer is there (firewalls permitting).  PsPing (Sysinternals) allows you to ping a port if that would be better.  I would suggest a scripting language that could test a HTTP response from a GET might be the best way to go. Something like: [test.vbs](http://pastebin.com/ET5dvytV) might give you a starting point.

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a simple check whether the server is up or not you could put all IP addresses in a file and call the following script with `script.bat urls.txt`:

```
@echo off
for /f %%a in (%1) do (
    echo Pinging %%a ...
    ping -n 1 %%a | find "Reply" > NUL
    if not errorlevel 1 (echo %%a is up) else (echo %%a is down)
)
```

`urls.txt` should look like this (just a list of IP addresses of your servers or urls):

```
www.google.com
www.amazon.com
10.2.1.12
8.8.8.8
```

Comment: I tried this. But where I can find the result ? I ran 'cmd', then put script.bat urls.txt. The cmd did not give me any result.

Comment: Have you actually tested this? This batch file contains at least 4 mistakes.

Comment: @Rauf, I updated the script

Comment: @DavidPostill, no I'm not on a Windows machine but the new script should work. feel free to edit!

Comment: @r3r57 Revised script works. Please test next time :)

Comment: How do your run this?

If my files are in this directory:

C:/BatchPing/url.txt C:/BatchPing/script.bat

I know what to put in URL, but what do I put into .bat file?

Also, what would be the exact code for this situation?

Do I need to substitute %%a and %1 with something?

Comment: The above script works fine. But if ping is prohibited for some URL/server, this batch script doesn't work. In this case, what should be the modified script ...?

Comment: You should probably use `find "TTL="` instead of `find "Reply"`.

Comment: @mivk is right. For IPv4 the "TTL=" is the most reliable method. The "Reply" is found even when there is an error "Destination host unreachable". Check this thread for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329749/batch-errorlevel-ping-response